# How to create a column and change it value by for loop?

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to python and pandas. I have searched many posts talking about how to change the value of dateframe by condition. However, how if I got a dataframe with a lot of condition?

I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

data = {"Project":["A","A","A","B","B"], "Date":[dt.datetime(2020,1,1),dt.datetime(2020,3,1),dt.datetime(2020,5,1),dt.datetime(2020,2,1),dt.datetime(2020,4,1)]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

```
    Project Date
0   A       2020-01-01
1   A       2020-03-01
2   A       2020-05-01
3   B       2020-02-01
4   B       2020-04-01
```

and I would like to get the following result:

```
    Project Date        Start       End
0   A       2020-01-01  2020-01-01  2020-05-01
1   A       2020-03-01  2020-01-01  2020-05-01
2   A       2020-05-01  2020-01-01  2020-05-01
3   B       2020-02-01  2020-02-01  2020-04-01
4   B       2020-04-01  2020-02-01  2020-04-01
```

I think I can create Start and End column by following method, but I would like to set the start date and end date for different project seperately.

```
for i in df['Project']:
    tmp = df[df['Project']== i ]
    df['Start'] = min(tmp['Date'])
    df['End'] = max(tmp['Date'])

    Project Date        Start       End
0   A       2020-01-01  2020-02-01  2020-04-01
1   A       2020-03-01  2020-02-01  2020-04-01
2   A       2020-05-01  2020-02-01  2020-04-01
3   B       2020-02-01  2020-02-01  2020-04-01
4   B       2020-04-01  2020-02-01  2020-04-01
```

And this is just a simple example. How if I have many project and Date. Can I use for loop to check the condition?
Is there any way to do this? Thanks a lot

Comment: You can see the original document about iterative https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html#pandas-dataframe-iterrows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#transformation) with `min` and `max` like:

```
gr = df.groupby('Project')['Date'] #create the grouped object
df['Start'] = gr.transform('min')
df['End'] = gr.transform('max')

print (df)
  Project       Date      Start        End
0       A 2020-01-01 2020-01-01 2020-05-01
1       A 2020-03-01 2020-01-01 2020-05-01
2       A 2020-05-01 2020-01-01 2020-05-01
3       B 2020-02-01 2020-02-01 2020-04-01
4       B 2020-04-01 2020-02-01 2020-04-01
```

or another way with `groupby.agg` and `merge` for the same result

```
df = df.merge(df.groupby('Project')['Date']
                .agg([('Start', 'min'), ('End', 'max')]), 
              on='Project', how='left')
```